# How do i fix my else if in jscript? It's not working

Tags: html, if-statement, jscript

i have a super simple jscript program ( in html file). if and else are working, but else if is never working...

```
var num1 = prompt("Enter first number");
var num2 = prompt("Enter second number");
function result(){
if(num1 == 10 || num2 == 10){
    alert("one of entered numbers is 10, great!")
    return true
}else if((num1+num2) == 10){
    alert("The sum of 2 numbers is 10, great!")
    return true
}else{
    alert("None of numbers, or the sum is 10")
    return false
}
}
alert("Result is: ", result())
```

So, if one of the numbers is 10 it shows first if, but if it's 5 and 5, or 6 and 4 - it always shows else, i don't understand why else if is always ignored...
And how can i alert a result (true/false)? it's always says "Result is:        "

Comment: The problem is that `prompt()` returns a string, and when you add two strings they are concatenated. So if you enter 5 and 5, you get `num1 + num2 == "55"`. You can fix this by converting to a number with `Number(num1)` or `+num1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your prompts are saving the input as strings, here I converted them to integers and it seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/fk0tr196/

```
var num1 = prompt("Enter first number");
var num2 = prompt("Enter second number");
num1 = parseInt(num1,10);
num2 = parseInt(num2,10);
function result(){
if(num1 == 10 || num2 == 10){
    alert("one of entered numbers is 10, great!")
    console.log(num1);
    return true
}else if((num1+num2)== 10){
        console.log(num1);
    alert("The sum of 2 numbers is 10, great!")
    return true
}else{
    alert("None of numbers, or the sum is 10")
    return false
    console.log(num1);
}
}
alert("Result is: ", result())
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! do you know, why alert(result()) doesn't show true/false - just blank?

Comment: You are trying to concatenate with , that isn't an operator for that. Try: alert("Result is: " + result());

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at type coercion, strict equality and the `prompt` function is js.
[The prompt function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) receives two optional arguments and returns a `string` (bare with me).

When your result function is called with, let us say, `num1 = 5` and `num2 = 5`, you actually have:

```
num1 = "5"
num2 = "5"
```

See the difference? If you don't believe me, just `console.log(typeof num1)` or num2 and check for yourself!

Now, when you use double equals, you allow type coercion to try to equality, or in another words, you accept that `5 equals "5"`. This sometimes is helpful but generally you'll want to avoid it and use `===`, which only evaluates `true` if VALUE and TYPE are the same.

In summary,

```
5 == "5" // true
5 === "5" // false
```

So, when one of your values is "10", the `if` statement is `true` and works. Any other case will fall into `else`, because when you `+` two strings you are actually concatenating them.
As it is, entering 5 on both prompts will result in `"55"` in the `else if` statement, thus leading to `false`.

There are some ways to convert a string to a number:
1- `Number(variable)`
2- `parseInt(variable)`
3- `+variable`

There are some differences with each but at this stage, you shouldn't be concerned